# Перенос строки после 10 символов

Tags: php

Есть вывод текста из базы `base['text']` . Там текст записан как: `это текст какой-то статьи бла бла бла прочти меня читатель` .

Вопрос, как сделать чтоб при выводе этого текста на странице он разбивался на строки(`<br />`) после каждого 15-го символа, но только чтобы не резал слова, типа:

```
это текст како
й-то статьи бла бла бла пр
очти меня читатель
```

Если уж не влазит на строку слова, то чтоб оно выводилось полностью, а уже после него перевод строки.

Как подобное реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проходите по тексту в цикле, по кусочкам отрезая строки.

```
function cutTextInLines($theText, $lineLength) {
    if (strlen($theText)<=$lineLength) return $theText;
    $lines = Array(); // здесь будем собирать вырезанные строчки
    do {
        $extendToPos = strpos($theText, ' ', $lineLength); // ищем ближайший пробел после 10-го знака
        $lines[] = substr($theText, 0, $extendToPos); // берем строчку
        $theText = substr($theText, $extendToPos); // вырезаем взятую строчку из общего текста
    } while (strlen($theText)>$lineLength);
    $lines[] = $theText;
    $lines = array_map('trim', $lines); // просто для внешнего вида убираем пробелы в начале и в конце строк
    return implode('<br />', $lines);
}

echo cutTextInLines($base["text"], 10);
```

Comment: У вас скобка лишняя в пятой строке.

Comment: С русскими буквами будут проблемы и обрезать может по пол буквы.

Answer (score 2):

Уже есть готовое решение, единственное у функции проблемы с многобайтовыми кодировками http://php.net/manual/ru/function.wordwrap.php

Comment: `$str = "Can be used to split a string into smaller chunks which is useful for e.g. converting";
print_r(wordwrap($str , 15 , "\n" , true));`