# Как сделать перенос строки по пробелу?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Нужно сделать перенос строк (записывать в массив)по пробелу по заданному размеру длины строки.

Пример:

```
$text = 'Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки. Если вызвана статически, возвращает объект класса DOMDocument или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки.';
class MyClass {

    public $output = array();

    public function text($text, $string_length){
         print_r($output);
    }

}
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->text($text, 20);
```

должно получиться:

```
Array ( [0] => Возвращает TRUE в [1] => случае успешного завершения [2] => или FALSE в случае возникновения [3] => ошибки. Если вызвана статически, [4] => возвращает объект класса DOMDocument [5] => или FALSE в случае возникновения )
```

Я решил таким путем:

```
class MyClass {

    public $output = array();

    public function text($text, $string_length){

        $i = 0;
        foreach(explode(' ', $text) as $val){
            if(!empty($this->output[$i])){
                if(iconv_strlen($this->output[$i], 'utf-8') < $string_length){
                    $this->output[$i] .= $val.'  ';
                } else {
                    ++$i;
                    if(isset($this->output[$i])){$this->output[$i] .= $val.'  ';}
                }
            } else {
                $this->output[$i] = $val.' ';
            }
        }
        print_r($this->output);
    }

}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->text($text, 20);
```

Но результат не верен:

```
Array ( [0] => Возвращает TRUE в [1] => успешного завершения [2] => FALSE в случае возникновения [3] => Если вызвана статически, [4] => объект класса DOMDocument [5] => FALSE в случае возникновения )
```

Пропадает начиная с **array [1]**. 
Т.е. должно быть: `[0] => Возвращает TRUE в [1] => СЛУЧАЕ успешного`
А слово **СЛУЧАЕ** теряется и вместо него вставляется **завершения**

Не претендую, что мой алгоритм лучший, но уже перепробовал несколько различных способов и этот вышел ближе всего к истине.

Comment: Посмотрите вот это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464557/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-10-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/464566#464566 - с небольшими изменениями можно использовать

Comment: Юрий, вы опубликовали много описаний меток, напрямую копируя содержимое из внешних источников. Так делать не нужно. Зайдите в чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довёл идеи автора до логического завершения.

1. Вариант №1.
   Конвертация строки в однобайтовую кодировку CP1251.
   Корректный вызов функции wordwrap в CP1251.
   Конверсия в исходную кодировку.
   Распаковка готовой строки в массив.

   ```
   class MyClass {
       public $output = array();    

       public function text($text, $string_length){
           $code_original = mb_detect_encoding($text);
           $text_cp1251 = mb_convert_encoding($text, "CP1251");
           $wrap_cp1251 = wordwrap($text_cp1251, 20,"<br>");
           $wrap_original = mb_convert_encoding($wrap_cp1251, $code_original, "CP1251");
           $this->output = explode("<br>", $wrap_original);
           print("<pre>"); print_r($this->output); print("</pre>");
       }
   }

   $text = 'Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки. Если вызвана статически, возвращает объект класса DOMDocument или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки.';
   $obj = new MyClass();
   $obj->text($text, 20);
   ```
2. Вариант №2 - доводка программы из текста вопроса.
   Копится сумма знаков в строке, а переход на следующую строку проводится, когда "примерка" с использованием нового слова даёт избыточную длину строки.

   ```
   class MyClass {

       public $output = array();    

       public function text($text, $string_length){

           foreach(explode(' ', $text) as $val){
               $len = iconv_strlen($val, 'utf-8')+1;
               if(empty($sum_prev)){
                   $sum_prev = $len;
                   $out_prev = $val;
                   continue; 
               }
               if(($sum_prev += $len) < $string_length+2){
                   $out_prev .= (' '.$val);
               } else { 
                   array_push($this->output, $out_prev);
                   $sum_prev = $len;
                   $out_prev = $val;
               }
           }
           array_push($this->output, $out_prev);
           print("<pre>"); print_r($this->output); print("</pre>");
       }

   }

   $text = 'Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки. Если вызвана статически, возвращает объект класса DOMDocument или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки.';
   $obj = new MyClass();
   $obj->text($text, 20);
   ```

Результаты совпали полностью:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Возвращает TRUE в
    [1] => случае успешного
    [2] => завершения или FALSE
    [3] => в случае
    [4] => возникновения
    [5] => ошибки. Если вызвана
    [6] => статически,
    [7] => возвращает объект
    [8] => класса DOMDocument
    [9] => или FALSE в случае
    [10] => возникновения
    [11] => ошибки.
)
```

Comment: Вариант 1 - более универсальный, потому что бывают и очень короткие строки.

Answer (score 0):

0) [Решение №0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464557/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-10-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/464566#464566) благодарю [cyadvert](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186791/cyadvert) :)

1) Решение №1

```
$text = 'Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки. Если вызвана статически, возвращает объект класса DOMDocument или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки.';

$word = explode(PHP_EOL, wordwrap($text, 40, "<br />\n"));
print_r($word);
```

2) Решение №2

```
$text = 'Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки. Если вызвана статически, возвращает объект класса DOMDocument или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки.';

class MyClass {

public $output = array();
public function text($text, $stringLength) {
        $words = explode(' ', $text);
$nextRow = '';
        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $calculatedRow = $nextRow . ' ' . $word;
if (iconv_strlen($calculatedRow, 'utf-8') <= $stringLength) {
                $nextRow = $calculatedRow;
            } else {
                $this->output[] = trim($nextRow);
                $nextRow = $word;
            }
        }
$this->output[] = trim($nextRow);
print_r($this->output);
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->text($text, 20);
```

Comment: Еcли бы решение №1 было адаптировано под кириллицу - цены бы ему не было!

Comment: Доработал обе идеи, ибо обе красивые и обе жалко )