# Как сделать перенос строки через каждые 50 символов?

Tags: php

Допустим, есть такая переменная:

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";
```

Как сделать перенос строки автоматически, чтобы в строке было не более 50 символов?

Comment: бежим посимвольно по строке, запоминаем в переменной пройденные символы, одновременно их считаем. Как видим пробел, если еще <50 печатаем запомненные символы, начинаем их копить с нуля. Если >50 то печатаем перевод строки и после него текущее слово, ставим счетчик символов на длину напечатанного слова

Comment: есть дубликат темы, там всё работает, и для кириллицы тоже http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469212/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83/469321#469321

Comment: @Mike это уже сделано)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть функция **[wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.wordwrap.php)**

```
string wordwrap ( string $str [, int $width = 75 [, string $break = "\n" [, bool $cut = false ]]] )
```

то есть для мыла так

```
$text = wordwrap($text, 50, "\n", true);
```

Comment: Данная функция переводит строку строго по 50 символов. Нужно так, чтобы если 50-й символ - это середина слова, то переносим строку на пробеле перед этим словом.

Comment: Вы прбовали? Там сказано что по словам. WORDwrap же.

Comment: Всё-таки работает, но как-то странно. У меня перенос строки происходит так, будто параметр cut делится на 2. Вместо 50 - 25, вместо 40 - 20 и т.д.

Comment: Это происходит с русским текстом.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов wordwrap utf8 не понимает. Так что только примерно как я предлагал, вот например уже готовый вариант на SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825226/multi-byte-safe-wordwrap-function-for-utf-8

Comment: @Mike дело в кириллице, она вообще кривая. Гляньте мою ссылку в комментах сверху - там и счётчик рабочий, и WORDwrap адаптированный. Wordwrap лучше на коротких строчках, потому что в крайних случаях умеет рвать слова.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
$mess = mb_substr($item['mess'], 0, 50, 'UTF-8') . '...';
```

Еще можно попробовать через html - заключить текст в div и для него задать фиксированную ширину/высоту.

Comment: переменная не выводится на странице, отправляется на e-mail.

Comment: Первый вариант не подходит?

Comment: А первый вариант просто обрезает строку, а не переносит.