# PHP Заменить перевод строки для c1251

Tags: php, кодировка

Необходимо заменить перевод строки на `//n`
Для кодировки UTF-8 срабатывает вот этот код:

```
$str_rez = preg_replace("#[\n\r]+#","\\n", $str_rez);
$str_rez = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '\\n', $str_rez);
```

Но вся база в `c1251` и перевод строки не заменяется. Делать перевод из `1251` в `utf8` пробовал, но появляются в тексте всякие знаки вопроса.
Желательно заменить перевод каретки без преобразования их кодировки в кодировку.

Comment: в принципе вторая строка должна справляться независимо от кодировки. Может сам файл какой-то неправильный?

Answer (score 1):

Перевод строки в HTML - это "<**br** >" во всех кодировках.
Его и заменяйте.

Comment: Если есть сомнения - посмотрите сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469212/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83/469321#469321